# reference to address of stack object

Tags: c++, reference

I am having difficulty understanding why below code does not compile under Visual Studio 2012, error already embedded in below code.
I feel it has something to do with referencing stack object, but not quite sure.
Can someone help?

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct Node {
    Node *next;
} Node;

void test(Node *&p) {
    p=p->next;
}

void main() {
    Node *p1=new Node();
    test(p1);   // this line compiles okay

    Node p={0};
    test(&p);    // error C2664: 'test' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Node *' to 'Node *&'
}
```

Comment: Gcc gives you a good diagnostic: *"error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Node*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Node*"* And answers your doubt competently.

Comment: Lol. Its deja-vu all over again.=P. The gcc error is about as concrete as you can get. The function is expecting a reference to an lvalue. You're passing an rvalue. There is no "there" there, so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

`&p` is not a variable of type `Node*`. It's a constant of type `Node*`.

Even if you could somehow take a reference to `p` and pass it to `test()`, `p=p->next;` would still fail because you can't assign to a constant.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks! I just started wondering what was wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing the down-voter was thinking something about the phrase "r-value" when he pulled the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a variable by address, not a pointer to a variable by reference. I think this will work:

```
void main() {
    Node *p1=new Node();
    test(p1);   

    Node p={0};
    Node* p2 = &p;
    test(p2);     
}
```